# AJAX response - selecting parent of where the post originated?

Tags: ajax, jquery

I am using an AJAX post to load all comments from a database.  I need the response to load only in the DIV that it originated from.

```
$('.viewCommentsExpBtn').click(function() {
    var trackid=$(this).parent().find(".trackidField2").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: "trackid="+trackid,
        url: "http://rt.erna.com/viewcomments.php",
        success: function(data) {
            var parent=$('.viewComments');
            $(parent).slideToggle();
            $(".userError").html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Right now the response is toggling all divs with the class "viewComments". Is it possible to toggle only in the originating DIV?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is right here:

```
var parent = $('.viewComments');
```

That, of course, selects everything with the `viewComments` class. All you need to do is figure out the correct `parent` outside your `$.ajax` call. Without knowing your HTML structure, I'd guess that you want this:

```
$('.viewCommentsExpBtn').click(function() {
    var parent  = $(this).parent();
    var trackid = parent.find(".trackidField2").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: "trackid="+trackid,
        url: "http://rt.erna.com/viewcomments.php",
        success: function(data) {
            parent.slideToggle();
            $(".userError").html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks!  I'll accept this in a minute.  Still learning my way around jQuery.